# How to sort string numeric array in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I am trying to sort an array mapped with other three arrays.
My main array is string+number i e `["Day 1","Day 2","Day 3"...]`
Other three array are also array of string.

Right now i am using following code.

```
var mainDayArray = ["Day 1","Day 2","Day 3","Day 4","Day 5","Day 6","Day 7","Day 8","Day 9","Day 10","Day 11","Day 12","Day 13"]
var timeArray = ["06:09 PM", "06:09 PM", "06:08 PM", "06:08 PM", "06:08 PM", "06:07 PM", "06:07 PM", "06:07 PM", "06:07 PM", "06:06 PM", "06:06 PM", "06:06 PM", "06:06 PM"]
var dateArray = ["Oct 1", "Oct 2", "Oct 3", "Oct 4", "Oct 5", "Oct 7", "Oct 4", "Oct 5", "Oct 9", "Nov 2", "Nov 3", "Nov 4", "Nov 01"]
var studentNameArray =["as","ab","vf","sd","fd","gr","ht","jh","kl","mn","sf","ts","at"]

let offsets = mainDayArray.enumerated().sorted { $0.element > $1.element }.map { $0.offset }

let sortedCompletedDayArray = offsets.map { mainDayArray[$0] }
let sortedCompletedDateArray = offsets.map { dateArray[$0] }
let sortedCompletedTimeArray = offsets.map { timeArray[$0] }
let sortedCompletedStudentNamesArray = offsets.map { studentNameArray[$0] }
```

But I am getting wrong data here. The output I am getting is below:

```
mainDayArray = ["Day 9","Day 8","Day 7","Day 6","Day 5","Day 4","Day 3","Day 2","Day 13","Day 12","Day 11","Day 1"]
```

Comment: Work with a custom struct instead of having the values in different arrays

Comment: Hi HangerRash this does not answer my question.
This only works for two arrays but i have 4 arrays.
And i am getting "No exact matches in call to subscript " issue when using this

Comment: @Abhishekkumar I would see JoakimDanielson's comment - it seems very weird to be working with four arrays which an "index dependent"

Comment: Hi Joakim actually it is already coded like this.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar Also, based on the linked example by HangerRash, I got your code to (I assume) to work (or at least `sortedCompletedDayArray` is in the correct order)

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes but i also want to map other arrays with that array.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar Yes, and, essentially, I think I got it to work - I'm just not going to take the time to valid the results.  Essentially, I replaced your `sorted` call to `.sorted { $0.element.compare($1.element, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending }` when calculating the `offsets` and then run your remaining code, which put `sortedCompletedDayArray` into order

Comment: “… it is already coded like this”, code can be changed :) I honestly believe it is the simplest and least error prone solution to refactor your code into using one array of a custom type than your current solution.

Comment: @MadProgrammer i tried replacing sorted call with new call that you given but i got "No exact matches in call to subscript " issue

Comment: `let offsets = mainArray.enumerated().sorted { $0.element.compare($1.element, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending }.map { $0.offset }` seems to work just fine for me

Comment: @MadProgrammer yay :) this works. Thanks a lot i was trying to fix it from yesterday. Thanks. :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes you are right sir. This code needs to be updated. But right now this issue was on the priority. :) I will look into  creating struct instead of using multiple arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Your day array already looks sorted but just in case it's possible that your day array can be unsorted here is my solution:

```swift
var mainDayArray = ["Day 1","Day 2","Day 3","Day 4","Day 5","Day 6","Day 7","Day 8","Day 9","Day 10","Day 11","Day 12","Day 13"]

var timeArray = ["06:09 PM", "06:09 PM", "06:08 PM", "06:08 PM", "06:08 PM", "06:07 PM", "06:07 PM", "06:07 PM", "06:07 PM", "06:06 PM", "06:06 PM", "06:06 PM", "06:06 PM"]

var dateArray = ["Oct 1", "Oct 2", "Oct 3", "Oct 4", "Oct 5", "Oct 7", "Oct 4", "Oct 5", "Oct 9", "Nov 2", "Nov 3", "Nov 4", "Nov 01"]

var studentNameArray = ["as","ab","vf","sd","fd","gr","ht","jh","kl","mn","sf","ts","at"]


let offsets = mainDayArray.map(parseNumber).enumerated().sorted { $0.element < $1.element }.map(\.offset)

let sortedCompletedDayArray = offsets.map { mainDayArray[$0] }
let sortedCompletedDateArray = offsets.map { dateArray[$0] }
let sortedCompletedTimeArray = offsets.map { timeArray[$0] }
let sortedCompletedStudentNamesArray = offsets.map { studentNameArray[$0] }

/// Parses the day number from an array element stored in the `mainDayArray`.
/// - Parameter element: An element from the `mainDayArray`.
/// - Returns: The day number.
func parseNumber(from element: String) -> Int {
    Int(element.split(separator: " ").last!)!
}
```

However, this code assumed your `mainDayArray` will always be in the form of `<string> + " " + <number>`. If you take a look at the `parseNumber(from:)` function it splits the elements from the point it detects a space, ie., `" "`, and then from all the split values it assumes the last one will be the number of the day. Then, it simply casts that into an integer.

From there it's pretty straightforward. It sorts those using `$0.element < $1.element` and `mainDayArray` will be sorted.

**Warning:** This will cause a crash if your `mainDayArray` isn't in the proper format. Feel free to edit the `parseNumber(from:)` method as you see fit. This was just a quick implementation I did. The goal of that method is to simply take an element from the `mainDayArray` and retrieve the day number from it. So as long as that is achieved by the function this code will work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to sort all arrays based on the `mainDate`'s order after sorting it (descending) by its values.

I suggest to first build a struct and encapsulate all data together like:

```
struct Student {
    let mainDate: String
    let time: String
    let date: String
    let name: String
}

let students = (0..<mainDayArray.count).map {
    Student(
        mainDate: mainDayArray[$0],
        time: timeArray[$0],
        date: dateArray[$0],
        name: studentNameArray[$0]
    )
}
```

Then you can sort by any property you want in the order you want like:

<sub>✅ Answer to your specific question about sorting number strings is here</sub>

```
let sortedStudents = students.sorted(using: KeyPathComparator(\.mainDate, comparator: .localizedStandard, order: .reverse))
```

<sub>Here I've sorted students based on their `mainDate` in the order of numbers. Note that passing `localizedStandard` will cause the `Day 9` to be ordered **after** the `Day 10` as expected.</sub>

Then if you actually need separated arrays, you can extract them from this source extremely simple like:

```
let sortedCompletedTimeArray = sortedStudents.map(\.time)
```